# use survfit with centered = FALSE, similar to basehaz

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, hazard

When using the `basehaz()` function (`basehaz()` calls on `survfit()`), there is an option to set `centered = FALSE`, which means hazard are not calculated relative to the mean of the predictors, but instead to when all values are zero.

This option does not appear to be present in `survfit()`, and when adding a `centered = FALSE` command to `survfit()`, the cumulative hazards do not change. I would like to use `survfit()`, as opposed to `basehaz()`, as it is more flexible, but I would also like the reference to be zero values. Is there a way to do this?

Source: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survival/versions/2.11-4/topics/survfit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right `survfit`, when taking a Cox model object, uses prediction at the means which is nonsense. If you want to obtain the survival function obtained from the baseline hazard function, you must use the `newdata` argument and predict the survivorship for a single participant having all covariates equal to 0.

As an example with the linked `ovarian` dataset in the help package:

```
> data(ovarian)
> fit <- coxph( Surv(futime,fustat)~resid.ds+rx+ecog.ps,data=ovarian)
> plot(survfit( fit, newdata = data.frame(resid.ds=0, rx=0, ecog.ps=0)))
```

[image]

Note the curve is substantially "higher" than the default predicted survival because the majority of covariates were deleterious. This is also projected to ranges of covariate values that make no sense for this dataset, so employ caution when predicting survival at 0 covariate values. See `?ovarian` for more help.

Comment: Using the newdata argument was something I had not considered, this is what I was after. Also I have been sure to make sure all my covariates have an interpretation at 0, thanks for the caution.